# Soft delete cascade with Eclipselink DescriptorCustomizer

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Dear fellow programmers I have come to you for asistance with the following:

I am using EclipseLink as the ORM for my application and am trying to implement Soft Delete on one of my entities (Article) and cascade delete these articles when a Catagory with a OneToMany relationship is deleted.

When I delete an Article everything works as expected but when I delete a Category which has n Articles I get an Exception. I am using a DescriptorCustomizer to accomplish the Soft Deletes.

The DescriptorCustomizer (see *org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer*) with the following implementation:

```
public class ArticleCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor classDescriptor) throws Exception {
       classDescriptor.getQueryManager().setDeleteSQLString("UPDATE article SET ACTIVE = '0' WHERE id = #id");
    }
}
```

The entities I'm trying to save:

AbstractItem

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractItem extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne
protected Category category;
}
```

Article

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("article")
@Customizer(value=ArticleCustomizer.class)
public class Article extends AbstractItem {

}
```

Category

```
@Entity
@Customizer(value=CategoryCustomizer.class)
public class Category extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(name = "category_items", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"))
    protected List<AbstractItem> items = new ArrayList<AbstractItem>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(name = "category_subcategories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id"))
    protected List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
}
```

The error when I try to cascade delete a Category which has n Articles:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ACTIVE' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: UPDATE article SET ACTIVE = '0' WHERE id = ?
bind => [null]
```

I can see the id was bound to null, however I do not understand why. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

1. Eclipselink version: 2.4.0
2. Spring: 3.1.2RELEASE

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Bart, the error message could be misleading (Unknown column ACTIVE) but just in case, can you verify that the ARTICLE table has a column called ACTIVE?

Comment: Also it would be worth naming the version of EclipseLink that you are working with.

Comment: You might also show the two entities and the exception stack.  Does it happen on any category, or is it reproducible only in a certain situation?

Comment: @RobKielty I can confirm that the column ACTIVE is present but not exactly in the ARTICLE table like I first said. It's actually a column in the ITEM table. Could this be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry to have waisted your time. The solution was right in front of me:

```
classDescriptor.getQueryManager().setDeleteSQLString("UPDATE item SET ACTIVE = '0' WHERE id = #ID");
```

The correct table for the customizer should have been *ITEM* instead of *ARTICLE*. Strangely enough it worked for single article deletes and did not work for cascades.

Second problem was:

```
#id instead of #ID
```

it's case sensitive.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Upvote for coming back and solving the mystery! Nothing worse than someone coming in, asking a question, fixing it and then saying nothing. Respect.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a class implements `DescriptorCustomizer` I would suggest wrapping its coding around with:

```
public static class MyCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
        try {
           ...
           ... your functionality 
           ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason is that `DescriptorCustomizer` produces silent fails,
when logging settings are lower than `FINER` (which is quite verbose). Then exceptions are not propagated to "outside" and you won't get a notice of them, nor can find out the reason for failing.

Alternatively, you could set the the EMF property `PersistenceUnitProperties.LOGGING_LEVEL` level to `SessionLog.FINER_LABEL`.